# What does the dot preceeding an operator mean in C?

Tags: c, operators

I'm not familiar with C and I'm trying to translate a piece of code I found to another language. For the most part, it's been rather intuitive but now i encountered a bit of code in which a subtraction operator is preceeded by a fullstop, like this:

```
double C;
C = 1.-exp(A/B)
```

I searched for it but all I can find about the dot operator is the standard property access of an object. I've encountered the '.-' operator in other langauges where it denoted element-wise operation on an array, but in my code none of the elements are arrays; all of A, B and C are doubles.

Comment: that's part of the number to make it a floating point constant.

Comment: The expression is parsed as `1.0 - exp(A/B)`.

Comment: The dot is not really preceeding the operator. It is part of the numeric value before.

Comment: If you add some spacing it might become clearer: `C = 1. -exp(A / B)`. Now, what do you think `1.` means?

Comment: Thank you all, rapid and helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It instructs the compiler to treat that literal number as a **floating-point** number.
`1. = 1.0`

- In your case `C = 1.-exp(A/B)` is equivalent to `C = 1.0 -exp(A/B)`